# How do i safely install a package with Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: .net, powershell, plsql, odac

I am using a variant of the folllowing script to install PL/SQL packages:

```
$con = [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]::new('....')
$con.Open()

$cmd = [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand]::new()
$cmd.Connection  = $con;

$cmd.CommandText = @'
create or replace package tq84_pkg_with_errors as
    proc should_read_procedure_not_proc;
end tq84_pkg_with_errors;
'@
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = @'
create or replace package tq84_pkg_without_errors as
    procedure xyz;
end tq84_pkg_without_errors;
'@
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to find out that `tq84_pkg_with_errors` was not installed other than checking `USER_OBJECTS` and/or `USER_ERRORS` for an error message.

Thus, I am wondering if there is a way to find out about an unsuccessful attempt to install a package with `Oracle.DataAccess`.

Comment: Does `ExecuteNonQuery` produce some sort of exception that is printed to the error stream or does it fail silently?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` does not produce some noticebly different output, let alone an exception, when trying to compile an invalid PL/SQL text (which prompted my question). I'd be happy if I had something like SQL*Plus's *Warning: Package created with compilation errors.*